# How to fix fbx import material(Reflection Issue)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, fbx

I developed 3d model with 3dsmax.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIr5Q.png)

But I have some issue.
I got this issue when import 3d model(FBX) to unity.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfG3h.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bciD6.png)

As you can see, model showed strangely.

Comment: you need to normalize and flip your normals

Comment: [read more here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/FBXImporter-Model.html)

Comment: I follow this guide but I can't fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1

you need to normalize and flip your normals.

download and install [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/)

import your fbx model, then in the mesh editor (default screen) recalculate your normals and then export your model into fbx again (always make a backup of your original file before you export, just to be safe)

[tutorial](https://www.katsbits.com/codex/flip-normals/)

## Solution 2

or you can disable backface culling on that 3d model in the renderer component